# Lex response is different depending on if I type the statement or use audio

Tags: amazon-lex

I am using the chat interface as provided in the lex builder. 
When I type a question I get a format back like the first example.
And Lex does not speak the response to me.

```
{
  "dialogState": "ElicitSlot",
  "intentName": "OrderFlowers",
  "message": "What type of flowers would you like to order?",
  "messageFormat": "PlainText",
  "responseCard": null,
  "sessionAttributes": {},
  "slotToElicit": "FlowerType",
  "slots": {
    "FlowerType": null,
    "PickupDate": null,
    "PickupTime": null
  }
}
```

However when I speak a question lex responds with voice. 
And the example response looks like:

```
slot-to-elicit: FlowerType
dialog-state: ElicitSlot
input-transcript: i would like to order some flowers
session-attributes: {}
slots: {
  "PickupTime": null,
  "FlowerType": null,
  "PickupDate": null
}
```

How does lex know to speak the response to the client in the second example considering there is no messageFormat specified? 
Both responses were taken from the detailed panel in the lex chatbot builder.

Answer (score 0):

After running some tests with it myself, it appears that the Lex Test Bot is set up to detect the incoming message type and alter the response to deliver the response message type to match.

Notice that the detailed panel information about the response from an audio input is only hiding the full response details, not lacking them.

In fact, the audio input response details shown are not even in correct Lex Response format.

```
slot-to-elicit        ----should be---->       slotToElicit
input-transcript      ----should be---->       inputTranscript
session-attributes    ----should be---->       sessionAttributes
```

This is enough evidence for me to conclude that the Lex Test Bot is designed to alter the Lex Response format to deliver the message as an audio output only when it received audio input.

To answer your question directly:

> How does Lex know to speak the response?

It's not Lex, it's the Test Bot. And it detects the input type.

> But there's no 'messageFormat' specified?

I can confirm that it **is** specified in the Lex Response and delivered to the Lex Test Bot. So the Test Bot must be handling the Lex Response in its own way.

> *Follow-up Question:* If the response is the same then why is the response details panel different?

Imagine if it showed the real response it received or the Test Bot's alterations, either would be misleading to developers. So for audio output messages it shows its own form of details in the response details panel.